# SQL where clause with seperataed IN expression to implement CNF

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpa, where-clause, conjunctive-normal-form

I need to query users according to thier dynamically added properties (transposed table)

I have 4 tables

- **users** - for users
- **propertyGroup** - for groups of properties, groups can be added dynamically to the db
- **propertyValue** - for possible values of propertyGroup
- **usersPropertyValues** - connect user to his relevant properties

Its look like this:

```
users:
------
| id | name | details |
|----|------|---------|
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |

propertyGroup:
--------------
| id |           name |
|----|----------------|
|  1 |        Hobbies |
|  2 |       LikeFood |
|  3 | VisitedCountry |

propertyValue:
--------------
| id | propertyGroupId |         name |
|----|-----------------|--------------|
|  1 |               1 | Technologies |
|  2 |               1 |      Surfing |
|  3 |               2 |         Rice |
|  4 |               2 |         Meat |
|  5 |               2 |          Veg |
|  6 |               3 |          USA |
|  7 |               3 |       FRANCE |
|  8 |               3 |       ISRAEL |
|  9 |               3 |       CANADA |

usersPropertyValues:
--------------------
| userId | propertyValueId |
|--------|-----------------|
|      1 |               1 |
|      1 |               2 |
|      1 |               3 |
|      1 |               5 |
|      1 |               6 |
|      1 |               7 |
|      1 |               8 |
|      2 |               2 |
|      2 |               3 |
|      2 |               4 |
|      2 |               5 |
|      2 |               8 |
|      2 |               9 |
|      2 |               7 |
```

so a mix-em-all query will look like this:

```
select * 
from users as u
 join usersPropertyValues as upv on upv.userId = u.id
 join propertyValues as pv on pv.id = upv.propertyValueId
 join propertyGroup as pg on pg.id = pv.propertyGroupId

| id | name | details | userId | propertyValueId | id | propertyGroupId |         name | id |           name |
|----|------|---------|--------|-----------------|----|-----------------|--------------|----|----------------|
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |      1 |               1 |  1 |               1 | Technologies |  1 |        Hobbies |
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |      1 |               2 |  2 |               1 |      Surfing |  1 |        Hobbies |
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |      1 |               3 |  3 |               2 |         Rice |  2 |       LikeFood |
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |      1 |               5 |  5 |               2 |          Veg |  2 |       LikeFood |
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |      1 |               6 |  6 |               3 |          USA |  3 | VisitedCountry |
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |      1 |               7 |  7 |               3 |       FRANCE |  3 | VisitedCountry |
|  1 |  Joe |     foo |      1 |               8 |  8 |               3 |       ISRAEL |  3 | VisitedCountry |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |      2 |               2 |  2 |               1 |      Surfing |  1 |        Hobbies |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |      2 |               3 |  3 |               2 |         Rice |  2 |       LikeFood |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |      2 |               4 |  4 |               2 |         Meat |  2 |       LikeFood |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |      2 |               5 |  5 |               2 |          Veg |  2 |       LikeFood |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |      2 |               8 |  8 |               3 |       ISRAEL |  3 | VisitedCountry |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |      2 |               9 |  9 |               3 |       CANADA |  3 | VisitedCountry |
|  2 |  Dan |     bar |      2 |               7 |  7 |               3 |       FRANCE |  3 | VisitedCountry |
```

its all here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49329/1

I want to query the data by a set of **propertyValueId** and get all the users that matches a this set of properties with regarding to the group so the user need to have at least on property from every group - in othe words, a where calause that matches the general CNF clause like this:
(pvId is abbreviation for propertyValueId)

```
Property group A        Property group B              Property group C
(pvId_x or pvId_y) and (pvId_w or pvId_z) and... and (pvId_m or pvId_k)
```

in the above example pvId_x&pvId_y belonges to group A, pvId_w&pvId_z belonges to group B etc.

what I did not working,
I tried to concat AND oparators of IN operators( in simulates the or part - the disjunctions) as showen here (query for the above sql fiddle):

```
select distinct u.name, u.id  
from users as u
 join usersPropertyValues as upv on upv.userId = u.id
 join propertyValues as pv on pv.id = upv.propertyValueId
 join propertyGroup as pg on pg.id = pv.propertyGroupId
 where (pv.propertyGroupId = 1 AND pv.id IN(1,2)) and (pv.propertyGroupId = 2 AND pv.id IN(5,6))
```

instead of getting both users (the both have (1 or 2) and (5 or 6) )  - i got none.

*I understand why the result set is empty but I don understand how to implement the right where clause. - how it can be done?*

**My Question:**
How can I implement the CNF logic in the above SQL structure?

**Edit:Excepted results examples:** (regarding the sqlfiddle example:

```
input  --> output 
{1,5}  --> Joe (user with hobby:tech, likefood:veg)
{2,8}  --> Joe,Dan (user with hobby:surfing, VisitedCountry:Israel)
{2,8,9}  --> Dan (user with hobby:surfing, VisitedCountry:Israel,Canada)
```

BTW, I need to implement this finally in JPA so if there is a solution in JPA it's also great. but if not - I will translate it... 
Thanks

Comment: you have all this beautiful data as an example and then you get to  your question and you don't show the expected result... please include that

Comment: thanks hogen - will do that in a sec

Comment: @Hogan - examples added

Comment: examples are horrible -- lucky I understand what you mean

Comment: @Hogan I need only the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your notation you want to query for all users that are associated with two propertyvalueid  (so {1,5} goes to property value ids of hobby:tech, likefood:veg)

Once you phrase it like that it is simple first get a list of one then get a list of the other and find the elements in both, like this:

```
select *
from users 
where id in (
  select userid from userPropertyValues where propertyvalueid  = 1
  intersect
  select userid from userPropertyValues where propertyvalueid  = 5
) sub
```

note I could use an inner join instead of the intersect operator but intersect is sexier.  If your platform does not support it just use a join.

---

As a join:

```
select *
from users 
join (select userid from userPropertyValues where propertyvalueid=1) a on a.userid = users.id
join (select userid from userPropertyValues where propertyvalueid=5) b on b.userid = users.id
```

or more simply stated as (this is AND condition - 1 and 5)

```
select *
from users 
join userPropertyValues a on a.userid = users.id and a.propertyvalueid=1
join userPropertyValues b on b.userid = users.id and b.propertyvalueid=5
```

---

(this is OR condition - 1 OR 5)

```
select *
from users 
left join userPropertyValues a on a.userid = users.id and a.propertyvalueid=1
left join userPropertyValues b on b.userid = users.id and b.propertyvalueid=5
where coalesce(a.userid, b.userid) is not null
```

You could also say

```
where a.userid is not null or b.userid is not null
```

### ---

from the fiddle

```
select *
from users 
where id in (
  select userid from usersPropertyValues where propertyvalueid  = 1
  intersect 
  (
  select userid from usersPropertyValues where propertyvalueid  = 3 
    UNION ALL
  select userid from usersPropertyValues where propertyvalueid  = 4
  )
);
```

lets see part before the intersect is

```
select *
from users 
join userPropertyValues a on a.userid = users.id and a.propertyvalueid=1
```

part after is

```
select *
from users 
left join userPropertyValues b on b.userid = users.id and b.propertyvalueid=1
left join userPropertyValues c on c.userid = users.id and c.propertyvalueid=5
where coalesce(b.userid, c.userid) is not null
```

so put them together (both are true for an intersect since it is the same as AND):

```
select *
from users 
join userPropertyValues a on a.userid = users.id and a.propertyvalueid=1
left join userPropertyValues b on b.userid = users.id and b.propertyvalueid=1
left join userPropertyValues c on c.userid = users.id and c.propertyvalueid=5
where coalesce(b.userid, c.userid) is not null
```

Comment: This looks like the solution, I added union all between every property group ie: "select * from users where id in ( (select.... union all select ..... ) intersect (select.... union all select ..... ) intersect ...(select.... union all select ..... )" in order to match the CNF structure (your solution isn't full) - how it can be done with 'JOIN' ?

Comment: @yossico -  I don't understand your union all comment and it sounds like a mistake but I would have to see the full text of your queries to be sure..  Join examples added to my answer.

Comment: You can see a detailed example with the union all part here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d830/1 . The main issue is that between all the values of the same catagory OR condition is needed and between groups - AND. is it possible to be implemented via Joins?

Comment: right, the intersect is an "AND" the union all is an "OR"

Comment: can you please show the example in the sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d830/1) as a join example? - instead of the intersect/union example there?

Comment: @yossico - ok I did it, but this is the last circus trick I'm going to do for you.  If you have additional "questions" ask them as a new question.  You are getting a little abusive of my good will here.   That last additional question was super simple once you understood my answer and you could have done it yourself I'm sure.  Please mark my answer as correct if it answers your question -- which I believe it does.

Comment: sorry for the late response, you really helped me here. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think it helps when you change and by or in the where clause

where (pv.propertyGroupId = 1 AND pv.id IN(1,2)) ***or*** (pv.propertyGroupId = 2 AND pv.id IN(5,6))

Comment: But in this case I will get user that have only "5" and have no 1 or 2